# does jQuery Validation plugin not work with input type number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validation plugin and attempting to validate an `<input type="number"/>` to ensure it is a number since Safari Mobile doesn't support the standard HTML5 validations. It works fine if its `type="text"`. Has anyone gotten this to work correctly or is it just a limit of the plugin?

Here's an example, if you enter a non-number it works correctly for the two text fields but not the 1st field (number input):

http://jsfiddle.net/rq5ra/397/

Comment: I've seen issues with `type="number"` and the jQuery Validate plugin.  However, keep in mind, that while using the jQuery Validate plugin, all HTML5 validation is automatically disabled by the plugin anyway.

Comment: @Sparky thats fine, ideally I'd like to keep the type as number so the iOS user will see the correct keyboard, but still validate it as a number

Comment: Until the developer fixes the issue, you can't.

Comment: use tel insted of number – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677323/html5-input-type-number-value-is-empty-in-webkit-if-has-spaces-or-non-numeric-ch

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski thanks for the suggestion, cool option except in this instance I need to be able to do decimal points as well.

Comment: You can add 'required' to this buggy field. For more details error comes from check method and from line `var val = this.elementValue(element);` String inside field with type number is evaluated to empty string. Empty string is valid number (wtf?)
You can ask how to fix this – solution will have something like `element.validity.valid` checker

Comment: **NOTE**:  The `type="number"` bug has reportedly been resolved as of jQuery Validate version 1.13 ~ 
See: [github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.13.0](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.13.0)

Comment: @sparky awesome! thanks for coming back to this question with an update.