# Adding a new parser on a form control

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a custom directive for inputs that will modify the model so that if a user types a number as "25,000" into the input, the model ends up with the value "25000" in integer form.

I have this code so far:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SomeController">
    <input type="number" name="some-field" ng-model="numericValue" integer />
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  app = angular.module('myApp')

  app.directive('integer', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) { return; }
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
          return parseInt(value.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
        });
      }
    };
  });

  app.controller('SomeController' ['$scope', function ($scope) {});
</script>
```

The directive will replace any non-numeric value in the value and run it through the `parseInt` method before returning the value. Problem is that the `value` argument of the parser method is always `null`, no matter what. Not sure if I'm using the wrong function or if there's something else wrong with my code.

---

**Edit** I created a sample of my app on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8A8b/). Try things like adding commas to the fields and see what the output becomes. I've found that a major part of the issue seems to be the numeric field type. When I use a text field type, then it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 input type=number value is empty in Webkit if has spaces or non-numeric characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677323/html5-input-type-number-value-is-empty-in-webkit-if-has-spaces-or-non-numeric-ch)

Comment: I believe you will have a hard time with this due to the implementation of the number type, specifically with Google Chrome.  If a number field contains a non-numeric value, it is seen as invalid and has an internal value of ''.

Comment: In case somehow you really get it works (e.g. by changing to use type="text"), don't forget to add a formatter to `ctrl.$formatters` as well to ensure the two-way binding won't break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my issue is not related to Angular, but to the browser implementation of `input[type=number]`. The `value` attribute is set to `null` in Chrome if the value is not a number.

[HTML5 input type=number value is empty in Webkit if has spaces or non-numeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677323/html5-input-type-number-value-is-empty-in-webkit-if-has-spaces-or-non-numeric-ch)