# Numeric keypad 8 and 9 crashes app - KnockoutJS + Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, knockout.js, phonegap-plugins

I am facing a strange issue in my project. I have used KnockoutJS for creating my UI. I am using latest version of Android Cordova. I have defined an HTML input type `number` in KnockoutJS

```
    <input maxlength="3" type="number" data-bind="maxLength: maxLengthSeats" placeholder="seats" />
```

However, when I run my app on Android device, the numeric keypad opens but when I enter either 8 or 9, my app crashes. There are no errors or logs. The app just stops with a white screen and I see the home screen of my device.

Why is the problem coming? I tried creating a fresh new Cordova project and added just one input number which is working. So what's the issue with Knockout ?

Has anyone faced such a problem when using Knockout in combination with cordova?

```
 //truncate value extender
  ko.extenders.truncateValue = function(target, option) {                            
  target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
      if(newValue.length > option){
          target(newValue.substring(0,option));
      }                    
   });

   return target;
};

 //maximum length extender
  ko.bindingHandlers.maxLength = {
   init:  function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,      
    viewModel) {
      'use strict';                     

      var maxlength = element.getAttribute("maxlength");

      valueAccessor().extend({truncateValue: maxlength })
      ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor,     
   allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);    
  }   
};
```

Comment: is maxLength a custom binding?  or are you attempting data-bind="attr: { 'maxLength': maxLengthSeats }"

Comment: @BryanDellinger: updated the question with code. I even tried removing the  custom binding but still the crash is there

Comment: Obviously the problem is not related to KO. I'm not sure about real reason but pay your attention to [this comment](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4103#issuecomment-6165850)

Comment: ...and [this issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5115) too.

Comment: @f_martinez: I have tried them. I didn't work for me. Also, if I create a simple cordova project from scratch and use an input type 'number' it works. but when I do it in my project containing KO it doesn't