# How to open Number keyboard for iOS , android if the html5 textbox type="text"?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, safari, android-browser

i have the following questions for html5 mobile textbox.

1. is there any option to open number keyboard for ios and android platform  if the input is `type="text"`.
2. issue i am facing here is,  if the textbox is  `type="number"`, not able to append  $, % symbols dynamically in the textbox(to reproduce this open html page in android or ios browser)

   is there any option to include $, % symbol in the textbox, if type must be type="number" the value not appearing in safari,chrome and android browsers.

**Sample:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bharathid/bFk9c/

open the above URL in firefox it's working fine, but while opening in chrome value disappeared.

**Note:**

in my case  not like to use $, % symbol in separate span.

**Reference**:

[iOS5 show numeric keypad by default without using type="number" or type="tel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222528/ios5-show-numeric-keypad-by-default-without-using-type-number-or-type-tel)

Comment: If You Want Only Number Key Bord I think You should go with user @Madhu answer.. i will work fine....

Comment: Thank you user @Don't B Negative... i am not Negative... Just Joking..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this...

```
<input type="number" />
<input type="tel" />
```

Both of these present the numeric keypad when the input gains focus.

Everything else seems to bring up the standard keyboard.

you can see [this](http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2013/09/19/input-type-number-and-ios-numeric-keypad/) For iOS

without using those we cant use any numbers key board... insence of Both `iOS` and `ANDROID`.

Comment: i am asking in html5 page. not a android page.

Comment: Can You Show that... I mean at the Part of HTML Code Where you are mentioning Key Board.. If its Default or 3rd Party Browser.. we many not Use this.. if its Your own Web view or web browser(negative browser) it will work...

Comment: if we are used type="number" it open number keybord by default, if we used type="text" it will open a normal keyboard.

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-html5-input-types-to-enhance-the-mobile-browsing-experience

Comment: yes it will be there for android But for window i dont know... and its also there for black berry,,,

Comment: Note that `type=number` will not allow commas to be input, in certain browsers. (Certain regions use commas instead of the decimal point.) https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization